# preferredMaxLayoutWidth not working in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I have tried to make a `UILabel` that is a certain width using `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` but no matter what I do it won't work. Can you help me? I have tries so many different combinations to make it work.

```
@IBAction func addBottomTextButton(sender: AnyObject) {

   if addBottomTextField.text.isEmpty == false {
      let halfScreenWidth = screenSize.width * 0.5
      let bottomScreenPosition = screenSize.width
      memeBottomText = addBottomTextField.text
      fontName = "Impact"
      let memeBottomTextCaps = memeBottomText.uppercaseString // --> THIS IS A STRING!

      labelBottom.text = memeBottomTextCaps
      labelBottom.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
      labelBottom.textAlignment = .Center
      labelBottom.font = UIFont(name: fontName, size: 32.0)
      labelBottom.sizeToFit()

      labelBottom.userInteractionEnabled = true
      labelBottom.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
      labelBottom.numberOfLines = 1
      labelBottom.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = screenSize.width
      labelBottom.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(true)

      var r = CGFloat(halfScreenWidth)
      var s = CGFloat(bottomScreenPosition)
      labelBottom.center = CGPoint(x: r, y: s)

      self.view.addSubview(labelBottom)
      self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: labelBottom, attribute:
         NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: labelBottom,     
         attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))

      dismissKeyboard()
   }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'it won't work'?

Comment: It doesn't have a maximum width, the label is still larger than the size I specify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by your code I'd say your problem was you haven't got your constraints setup correctly and you're mixing using `NSLayoutConstraint`s with setting the position using `center` and setting the size using `sizeToFit`.

**Firstly,** in the constraint you've setup you're relating `labelBottom` (the `item` argument) to itself (the `toItem` argument). I'm not exactly sure what you were trying to achieve with that? I'd recommend having a look at some tutorials on AutoLayout if you're unfamiliar with its concepts. Here's a good one: http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1

**Secondly,** just a small point, on the line `let memeBottomTextCaps = memeBottomText.uppercaseString` you've written `// --> THIS IS A STRING`. An easier way to remind yourself of the variable type when looking back at your code could be to use: `let memeBottomTextCaps: String = memeBottomText.uppercaseString`.

**Thirdly,** `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` isn't used to set the width of a `UILabel` - that's what the `frame` is for (or `NSLayoutConstraint`s if you're using AutoLayout).

**Lets get on with it!**

Here's an example of how to create a label that is pinned to the bottom edge of its container view and is not allowed to be wider than it's container: (Keep in mind that all this can be done in IB)

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let label = UILabel()
        // 1.
        label.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        // 2.
        label.text = // Put your text here.

        // 3.
        self.view.addSubview(label)

        // 4.
        let pinToBottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label,
            attribute: .Bottom,
            relatedBy: .Equal,
            toItem: self.view,
            attribute: .Bottom,
            multiplier: 1.0,
            constant: -8.0)

        // 5.
        let horizontalConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("|-8-[label]-8-|",
            options: .DirectionLeadingToTrailing,
            metrics: nil,
            views: ["label" : label])

        // 6.
        self.view.addConstraint(pinToBottomConstraint)
        self.view.addConstraints(horizontalConstraints)
    }
}
```

The following referrers to the commented numbers in the code above.

**1.** You need to set `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `false` to stop constraints being created that would otherwise conflict with the constraints we're going to create later. Here's the what Apple have to say about it:

> Because the autoresizing mask naturally gives rise to constraints that fully specify a view’s position, any view that you wish to apply more flexible constraints to must be set to ignore its autoresizing mask using this method. You should call this method yourself for programmatically created views. Views created using a tool that allows setting constraints should have this set already.

**2.** You need to make sure you put your own text here, otherwise the code won't run.

**3.** The label **must** be added to the view hierarchy before adding constraints between it and it's superview! Otherwise, in this case, you'll get a runtime error saying:

> Unable to parse constraint format: 
>   Unable to interpret '|' character, because the related view doesn't have a superview 
>   |-8-[label]-8-|

This is due to our `horizontalConstraints` needing to know the label's superview (the superview is denoted by the `"|"`) but the label doesn't have a superview.

**4.** The `pinToBottomConstraint` constraint does what it says. The constant of `-8` just specifies that I want the label to be 8 points from the bottom of its container view.

We don't **need** to create a constraint to specify the label's size - that's an intrinsic property of the `UILabel` which is determined, for example, by the number of lines and font.

**5.** The `horiontalConstraints` are created using Visual Format Language. Here's a good tutorial: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/introduction-to-the-visual-format-language--cms-22715 Basically, `"|-8-[label]-8-|"` creates constraints to pin the left and right edges of the label to the left and right edges of its superview.

**6.** Finally add the constraints!

This is what it looks like:

[image]

I hope that answers your question.

Comment: WOW! That is really beyond what I would call just an answer. I am so grateful!

Comment: I have done that and it works very well. However it knocks out the ability the code had to update the text when I press the button with new text (it now adds it on top) and the code below doesn't change the font either.       @IBAction func gagalinFontButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    fontName = "gagalin"
    labelBottom.font = UIFont(name: fontName, size: 32.0)
    labelTop.font = UIFont(name: fontName, size: 32.0)
Lastly the link to the tutorial doesn't work?

Comment: Which is the link that doesn't work? In response to your other questions: the fact that is it added on top suggests that you've got two labels? Are you calling my code in your `gagalinFontButton` method? If you need to update the label's attributes you should keep a reference to the label as a variable in your view controller. Also, I tried updating the font with the font you gave and I believe the problem is the font wasn't found. Try replacing `"gagalin"` with `"Arial"` to see if it works.

Comment: I have a label on the top and the bottom. I changed the attributes so they fit in both top and bottom  of the UIView very nicely. I have added the fonts to the project and they worked yesterday with the code I used before. I used a delegate on the textfield so the labels were updated every time I pressed the add text button and the font was updated when called the gagalinFontButton. I can't see why that has changed and it adds new labels on top another every time I press the addBottomTextButton.

Comment: Could you add your code as an edit to your question?

Comment: I fixed it I had declared the UILabel initially as a variable. Then in the code above it is a constant (let) so it wouldn't allow it to change. All working perfectly when I removed the  let label = UILabel().

Answer (score 0):

I think the property only work for multiline situation.

```
// Support for constraint-based layout (auto layout)
// If nonzero, this is used when determining -intrinsicContentSize for multiline labels
@available(iOS 6.0, *)
open var preferredMaxLayoutWidth: CGFloat
```

And it indeed true after my test.  So, we need set multiline. It will work.

```
titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0
```

I don't why Apple limit it to only multiline. In fact, we often need to set max width on label easily by one property.

Finally, if we want set max width , we need set max constaint, like the following

```
        if device.isNew == "1" {

            self.title.mas_updateConstraints { (make) in
                    make?.width.lessThanOrEqualTo()(163.w)
            }

            self.newTag.isHidden = false
        } else {

            self.newTag.isHidden = true

            self.title.mas_updateConstraints { (make) in
                make?.width.lessThanOrEqualTo()(207.w)
            }

        }
```